# Code review: TS React app UI language state implementation

Tags: reactjs, typescript

### The question (code review)

I have a plan of how to implement UI language state in a React app written in TypeScript. I seek feedback.

What's the common, "professional" convention in creating UI language states?

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this than my initial plan below?

### The plan

I intend to have buttons that change the selected language in the app's state (e.g. string `"default"` for English or string `"fin"` for Finnish). In the final product I'd be using Redux, I think.

The <strike>first</strike> second idea of possible implementation that came to my mind is to have all strings that are going to be rendered in the UI stored in a `texts.ts` module with the following structure:

```js
export type LanguageOption = "default" | "fin" | "esp";

interface Dictionary {
  [key: string]: Translations;
}

type Translations = {
  [key in LanguageOption]: string;
};

const texts: Dictionary = {
  "initial greeting": {
      "default": "Hello world!",
      "fin": "Terve maailma!",
      "esp": "¡Hola Mundo!"
  },
  "bacon": {
      "default": "bacon",
      "fin": "pekoni",
      "esp": "tocino"
  },
  // ...and a lot more...
};

export default texts;
```

Then, the texts could be used in the React app as follows:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import texts, { LanguageOption } from "./texts";

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [lang, setLang] = useState<LanguageOption>("default");

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={(): void => setLang("default")}>eng</button>
      <button onClick={(): void => setLang("fin")}>fin</button>
      <p>
        {texts["initial greeting"][lang]}
      </p>
      <p>
        {`I like ${texts["bacon"][lang]}!`}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

What would you do differently?

Comment: Post it on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) :) And take a look at [i18next /
react-i18next](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know of such place before! @pzaenger